# Joining tables depends on activity and activity id

Tags: mysql, sql

i need to do a search query whitch will look for result in 2 separated tables depending on activity.
The problem is, they are joining the same id. Right now its not working properly..

Table log

```
id     activity     activityid
1       news          155
2       prod          232
3       news          412
```

Table news

```
id       title     
155      Something    
412      Something
```

Table product

```
id       intro     
232      Something     


SELECT *
FROM log l 
INNER JOIN product p ON l.activityid=p.id and l.activity='prod'
INNER JOIN news n ON l.activityid=n.id and l.activity='news'
WHERE p.title like '%something%' or n.intro like '%something%'
```

What am i missing?

Comment: You're missing 3 things: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Sorry, ill keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you should use left join instead of inner join:

```
SELECT *
FROM log l 
LEFT JOIN product p ON l.activityid=p.id and l.activity='prod'
LEFT JOIN news n ON l.activityid=n.id and l.activity='news'
WHERE p.title like '%something%' 
    or n.intro like '%something%'
```

Anyway, please follow Strawberry suggestion...

Answer (score 1):

May be Use Left Join and alias names are mismatched `n.title` and `p.intro`.

```
SELECT *
FROM log l 
LEFT JOIN product p ON l.activityid=p.id and l.activity='prod'
LEFT JOIN news n ON l.activityid=n.id and l.activity='news'
WHERE n.title like '%something%' 
    or p.intro like '%something%'
```